# Why is "Hidden Features of C#?" closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, community-wiki, locked-posts

I travelled around SO and then I found [Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c?rq=1) .

What do you think about repeatedly opened & closed questions like that?

It's a big list of C# functions which are not known by most devs.

It's on the Wiki and I'm asking myself "why the heck is this Wiki thread closed?"

And "Why do we have a wiki" if there can't be any kind of "not an actual question" posts?

If you're looking at the edit history you can see that the community isn't sure if it's OK to be locked/deleted:

> #Newer
> Notice added Historical significance by Bill the Lizard
> Post Locked by Bill the Lizard
> Post Undeleted by Bill the Lizard
> Post Deleted by Gilles, tchrist, chown, Johannes Schaub - litb, yoda, redsquare, Bo Persson, Andrew Barber, John Saunders, Ninefingers
> Post Closed as "not constructive" by casperOne
> Post Reopened by Neil N, ulrichb, Adam Rackis, Alan, Glenn Slave
> Post Closed as "not constructive" by Gilles, Tim Cooper, yoda, Joe, geoffspear
> Question Protected by Robert Harvey♦
> Notice removed Historical significance by Robert Harvey♦
> Post Unlocked by Robert Harvey♦
> Post Reopened by Will
> Notice added Historical significance by Will
> Post Locked by Will
> Post Closed as "not constructive" by Will
> Notice removed Historical significance by Will
> #Older

Comment: Do you truly believe that's a good, on topic question for SO?

Comment: 1.Thing: It's in the wiki and it's a damn good list if your looking for some shortcuts.

Comment: Ok. But do you truly believe that's a good, on topic question for SO?

Comment: 2.Then we should need an extra tab for such posts

Comment: Ok. But do you truly believe that's a good, on topic "post" for SO? SO is not a forum. SO is a repository of __quality__ Q/A

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: @Hille: no, we don’t. Stack Overflow does not need to be the everything for everyone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters right now I can't see a proper advantage of the wiki.

Comment: @Hille: it's for making it easy to collaborate on posts, lowering the bar for entry. Wiki posts are not a get-out-of-the-topic-jail-for-free card.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I never thought it would be, but why isnt there any clear rule for stuff like that? You can see in the edit log that it was unlocked by  `Rober Harvey♦`.

Comment: @Hille: that post was re-opened in error, you'll note it is closed and locked now. We use humans to handle moderation tasks, and humans are not infallible. Don't take isolated examples as proof of general policy.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it was in his history more than 3 times accidentally reopened and that's what I mean, it's not clear if it should be closed or stay open.

Comment: @Hille: hrm, perhaps we are talking about a different post now? At any rate, guidelines and policies also *change over time*, as we learn what works and doesn't work on this site. So I'll amend my recommendation: don't use old posts as examples of what should be permitted today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[At the moment (10th Jan 2018) there appears to be an issue with closed and locked posts that means only the fact that it's closed is shown to the user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305582/post-banners-missing).

There should be a notice that the post is locked for what we term "historical reasons" as the question is **no longer** the type of question we want on the site but was once accepted and as it as a large number of views (and votes) it would, in some way, make the internet worse if we removed it.

The lock is there to indicate that we don't want questions of this type any more.

Answer (score 9):

> Right now it's on the Wiki and I'm asking myself why the heck is this Wiki thread closed?
>   And why do we have a wiki if there can't be any kind of "not an actual question"-like posts?

Making something a "Community Wiki" doesn't change what rules apply to said thing.

Community wiki questions are still expected to be quality questions.
Community wiki answers are still expected to answer the question.

A detailed explanation of what community wiki posts are, [can be found on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: I read it already, but I think right now it's pretty useless :o

Comment: @Hille If you think it's useless, that's fine.  Thinking that it means that a CW question doesn't need to follow the rules, as you've said repeatedly, is *not* fine.